# Question on signing a file with RSA (openssl)

Tags: rsa, signing

I'm read that either signing or encrypting (or both?) with RSA has a file size limit. One way I saw to tackle that was to take the sha256sum value of the file then sign that with RSA. Ultimately, I would like to sign a license file with RSA private key, so the destination application can verify it hasn't been altered (using public key)...

I found these script which sign and verify:
https://gist.github.com/ezimuel/3cb601853db6ebc4ee49

My questions are...

1. Is there a file size limit when you sign (not encrypt) with RSA?
2. If so, is signing the sha256sum of the file a valid way around the file size limit?
3. I see in the sign.sh script (in link above) is using a -dgst sha256 in the command. Is that taking the sha256sum value of the file and signing that, similar to #2? Or, if not, what is it doing?

I just want to make sure a license file isn't altered in transit. I was just going to append the signature to the bottom of the file. Then, have the application run a script separate the two (content and signature) to verify no changes have been made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming or development question. Yes, the usual way to sign (and verify) with RSA is to hash the data and apply the RSA privatekey and publickey operations to the hash _plus padding_ (very important; systems not using padding have been broken). Historically this was sometimes described as 'encrypting with the privatekey' but that also led to flaws and breaks, so is now strongly deprecated; see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/#159289 (mine). And yes this is what `openssl dgst -$hashname { -sign privkeyfile | -verify pubkeyfile }` does.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use `openssl cms` (or the largely equivalent but older `openssl smime`) to generate _either_ a detached signature which you send along with the data and contains metadata to help ensure correct verification without needing manual instructions or fixed conventions that can't be changed when needed, _or_ a message that contains the data _and_ signature and allows both robust verification _and_ extraction of the data. (CMS is Cryptographic Message Syntax, the successor to PKCS7, and S/MIME is effectively a wrapping of CMS designed for email but usable without.)

Comment: Is the padding step you mention also included in `openssl dgst -$hashname { -sign privkeyfile | -verify pubkeyfile }`?